# Creating new angular project in specified location

Tags: angular, cmd, command-prompt

I am new to angular 2 and I am trying to create a new project in E drive. I am using node.js command prompt for this.

When I just run ng new myapp , it automaticlaly creates project in
c drive but I wan to create the same  in E:drive under folder "angular4"

I am trying below but it is not working. could  you please correct me

This path shows up when we open command prompt

C:\Users\User1>

and to create new project in E: drive under angular 4 , I write below which is not working

```
C:\Users\User1>cd\ E:Angular4 ng new myapp
```

Answer (score 7):

First go to E drive then change the folder (cd Angular4)
then run

```
ng new myapp
```

EDIT:
Or you can concatenate the commands

```
 E: & cd Angular4 & ng new myapp
```

EDIT:
For Windows PowerShell, concatenate all these commands using the semicolon (;) operator, as:-

```
E:; cd Angular4; ng new myapp
```

Comment: can't this be run in a single statement like \cd\E: angular4 ng new myapp?

Comment: you can concat command i guess
like

E: & cd Angular4 & ng new myapp

Answer (score 3):

Use --directory option.

$ ng new myAngularApp --directory ./

Answer (score 1):

1. Open you command prompt.
2. Type `E:`
3. Type `cd Angular4`
4. Run `ng new myapp`

Comment: can't this be run in a single statement like \cd\E: angular4 ng new myapp?

Comment: You can do it by: cd E:\Angular4
And then run ng new myapp

PS: You can't directly run the ng command while changing into directory.
First you have to move to particular directory and then you can use ng command.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular cli for this purpose. Steps:

1. First goto E drive , type `E:`
2. `mkdir Angular4`
3. globally install angular cli using this command: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
4. Generate a project and run accordingly using:

   `ng new PROJECT_NAME
   cd PROJECT_NAME
   ng serve`

Answer (score 1):

Use cd-space-tab command to change directory

```
PS D:\Branches-2019\WT> cd..
PS D:\Branches-2019> cd..
PS D:\> cd .\Backup\
PS D:\Backup> cd '.\My Work\'
PS D:\Backup\My Work> cd .\2019\
PS D:\Backup\My Work\2019> cd..
PS D:\Backup\My Work> cd .\2020\
PS D:\Backup\My Work\2020> cd .\Hackathon\
PS D:\Backup\My Work\2020\Hackathon>
```